# Data not following tick position while being plotted

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm trying to plot a graph where I can change the position of my tick/labels and the plot actually follow these positions. Right now, it's not happening. What is the proper way to plot this? Basically, I want the plot to follow the tick position.

Thank you

```
the Data:

    MAG   variable          value
0    ZC4RG01  DAY01_tpm  436560.520594
1    ZC4RG02  DAY01_tpm  478950.594993
2    ZC4RG03  DAY01_tpm   64427.048996
3    ZC4RG04  DAY01_tpm  169800.918347
4    ZC4RG05  DAY01_tpm   40096.842341
5    ZC4RG06  DAY01_tpm   84662.286917
...
```

This is the piece of code that I have

```
melted_df = TPM_df.melt(id_vars='MAG')

g = sns.FacetGrid(melted_df, col='MAG', col_wrap= 2,height=4)

g.map(sns.pointplot, "variable", "value", color=".3", ci=None)
g.set(xlabel='', ylabel='TPM')
g.set(xticks=[1,3,7,15,30,64,67,78,99],xticklabels=['DAY01','DAY03','DAY07','DAY15','DAY30','DAY64','DAY67','DAY78','DAY99'])
g.set_titles(col_template = '{col_name}')
```

This is what I have right now

[image: chart]

What I want

[image: chart]

Comment: Where are your y-values? This is an incomplete example.

Comment: My y value came from the value column in melted_df. We don't need the y value to change the x axis in this case.

Comment: I do have problems understanding what the desired output here would be.

Comment: I want the graph plot to follow the tick position.

Comment: What does "follow the tick position" mean? Try to explain how you would envision the final graph to look like.

Comment: Your problem is that the data are plotted against the index of your DataFrame (first column of the data you show), while what you apparently want is the x values that you use for the xticks, i.e. `1,3,7,15,...`. So I'm guessing your best bet would be to add these xtick values as an additional column to your data and tell sns to use that column for the x values.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest.. I uploaded a figure where you can see the last image that I want.

Comment: @ThomasKühn I tried to create a new column with melted_df['POS'] = np.select(conditions, choices), setting the position there and trying to plot it, but the grid axis works different... :(

Comment: I see. The suggestion above is useful. Why not retain the number from the string like `df["number"] = df["variable"].map(lambda x: int(x[3:5]))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. I kept trying this for my own and I found the solution...
First I created a column within the position on the graph (as commented before). After that I used this POS as X axis while ploting. The secret, in this case, was to use seaborn.lineplot instead of seaborn.pointplot. It took me days to solve this, but now it's working. 
Ty for who tried to help and not judge :)